# Export from existing conan project the source code of all dependencies

Tags: c++, conan

I'm developing a C++ project using the [Beast boost library](https://github.com/boostorg/beast) through conan package manager:

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
boost_beast/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# ...
include( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake )

conan_basic_setup( TARGETS )

add_executable( ${ProjectName}
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp )

target_include_directories( ${ProjectName}
  PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include )

target_link_libraries( ${ProjectName} CONAN_PKG::boost_beast )
# ...
```

Does conan provide an automatic way (or even semi-automatic, easy way) for me to export the whole project in a sort of a *bundle* with all the required source code included (i.e. all library code also) in order for some third party to compile it without access to internet or precompiled binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Conan does not provide such feature, but you can use [Artifactory](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory_ce.html).

Conan will download the source files only when required, which means, when there is no pre-built binary and you need to build, or you are forcing to build from source. So, Conan will download the source files to your local cache. This cache is not shared.

However, if you want to distribute your packages, including source files when required for a build, I would say Artifactory is the best option. You can mirror your packages from Bintray and run a local instance of Artifactory.